# Intellij IDEA doesn't resolve Gradle dependencies

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm using Intellij `IDEA 2017.2.4` and `Gradle 4.0.1`
I have few Spring Boot services. And I facing a problem to run them, they can fail while starting in a random way because of missing dependencies.

I have a parent project with `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        mavenLocal()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:$dependencyManagementPluginVersion")
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$springBootVersion")
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'idea'

    group = '***'
    version = '***'
}

subprojects {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    processResources {
        filesMatching('**/*.yml') {
            expand(project.properties)
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    dependencyManagement {

        imports {
            mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:$springCloudVersion")
            mavenBom("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:$springBootVersion")
        }

        dependencies {
            dependency "com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:$googleCloudStorageVersion"
            ...
            dependency "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$junitVersion"
        }
    }
}
```

And a child project `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    ...
    testCompile('com.h2database:h2')
}
```

In some cases `lombok` dependency is missed, in other `javax` dependency. It shows that dependencies are not there.

[image]

But after I press `Refresh All Gradle Projects` and build once again it works.

[image]

Maybe someone encountered the same issue and have some solution for it?

Comment: Can you post your `build.gradle` file here, please?

Comment: @AndriiAbramov there are some basic things, nothing special

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have problem with `lombok` dependency. First step is to ensure that lombok is added as your compile time dependency for example:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.18'
}
```

Second step is to ensure that you have newest `lombok` plugin installed on your Intellij. It is very important when you are trying to compile your project inside IDE. Another thing that may help is setting to autoupdate dependencies in Intellij configuration.

Comment: Everything is up to date and also I have lombok dependency with the same version.